# TFS create project error TF30224

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, tfs

Our TFS 2008 2-tier setup was working fine until this morning when I attempted to add a new project.  When I go through the steps to add a project I get the following errors:

Error 
TF30224: Failed to retrieve projects from the report server. Please check that the SQL Server Reporting Services Web and Windows services are running and you have sufficient privileges for creating a project.

Explanation 
The Project Creation Wizard encountered a problem while creating reports on the SQL Server Reporting Services on TSGMKETFSAPP1. The reason for the failure cannot be determined at this time. Because the operation failed, the wizard was not able to finish creating the SQL Server Reporting Services site.

I have checked that the SQL Server Reporting Services is running and I am using an account that I have created a dozen other projects with.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to reinstall Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on the TFS server.

It seems that if you install SP1 before installing the TFS Team Explorer, you get this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you might not have the correct permissions.
Check out the following page for how to Set Administrator Permissions for Reporting Services.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253091(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it tooks months to figure out.
having tried lots of reconfigured permissions the solution was a simple reinstall of sp1 !